# Sql Server Computed Column Formula syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, calculated-columns

I want to use a computed bit column that will be true if another column in the table is not null.  What's the correct formula for this?

```
HasLabel = computed column (bit)
Label = varchar NULL
```

The following formula does not validate. - what am I missing?
Formula for HasLabel = `Label IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A computed column must return a value, whereas you are just doing a comparison. Try this instead:

```
case when label is null then 0 else 1 end
```

SQL Server will not understand this as a non-NULLable column however. To handle that, change the computation to:

```
isnull(case when label IS NULL then 0 else 1 end, 0)
```

Comment: Or `ISNULL(CASE WHEN label IS NULL THEN 0 END, 1)` is a bit shorter.

Comment: @MartinSmith And this one is a bit shorter still: `isnull(case when label > 1 then 1 end, 0)`